# Subset all 3 digit numbers and collapse them with a separator in a data frame. R

Tags: regex, r

I'm formating a data set so each entry has the adegenet format for codominant markers, such as:

```
Loci1
###/###
208/210
200/204
198/208
```

where the # represents any digit (the number is a allele size in basepairs). My data has some homozygous entries (all 3 digit integers with no separator) that have the the form of:

```
Loci1
###
208
198
```

I intend to `paste` the 3 digit string to itself with `sep='/'` to produce the first format. I've tried to use grep to subset these homozygous entries by finding all non `###/###` and negating the match using the table matching such as:

```
a <- grep('\\b\\d{3}?[/]\\d{3}', score$Loci1, value =T )  # Subset all ###/###/
score[!(a %in% 1:nrow(score$Loci1)), ] # works but only on vectors...
```

After the subset I could `paste`. The problem arises when I apply this to a data frame. `grep` seems to treat the data frame as a list (which in part it is) and returns columns that have a match.

So in short  how can I go from `###` to `###/###` in a data frame

self contained example of data:

```
score2 <- NULL
set.seed(9)
Loci1 <- NULL
Loci2 <- NULL
Loci3 <- NULL
for (i in 1:5) Loci1 <- append(Loci1, paste(sample(seq(from = 230, to=330,  by=3), 2, replace = F), collapse = '/'))
for (i in 1:5) Loci2 <- append(Loci2, paste(sample(seq(from = 230, to=330, by=3), 2, replace = F), collapse = '/'))
for (i in 1:5) Loci3 <- append(Loci3, paste(sample(seq(from = 230, to=330, by=3), 2, replace = F), collapse = '/'))

score2 <- data.frame(Loci1, Loci2, Loci3, stringsAsFactors = F)
score2[2,3] <- strsplit(score2[2,3], split = '/')[1]
score2[5,2] <- strsplit(score2[3,3], split = '/')[1]
score2[1,1] <- strsplit(score2[1,1], split = '/')[1]
score2[c(1, 4),c(2,3)] <- NA
score2
```

Comment: Your example code produces warnings.

Comment: Excuse me for that, I was in a hurry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just replace the 3 digit items with the separator and a copy:

```
 sub("^(...)$", "\\1/\\1", Loci1)
```

Use `lapply` with an anonymized function:

```
data.frame( lapply(score2, function(x) sub("^(...)$", "\\1/\\1", x)  ) )
    Loci1   Loci2   Loci3
1 251/251    <NA>    <NA>
2 251/329 320/257 260/260
3 275/242 278/329 281/320
4 269/266    <NA>    <NA>
5 296/326 281/281 326/314
```

(Not sure what the "paste-part" was supposed to refer to, but I think this was the intent of your question)

If the numeric values could have a varying number of digits then use a pattern argument like `"^([0-9]{1,9})$"`

Comment: I had the idea of using an index to subset and then paste the objects; I'll edit the question to remove that part.

Answer (score 2):

An option using `grep/paste`,

```
m1 <- as.matrix(score2)
indx <- grep('^...$', m1)
m1[indx] <- paste(m1[indx], m1[indx], sep="/")
as.data.frame(m1)
#    Loci1   Loci2   Loci3
#1 251/251    <NA>    <NA>
#2 251/329 320/257 260/260
#3 275/242 278/329 281/320
#4 269/266    <NA>    <NA>
#5 296/326 281/281 326/314
```

Or without converting to `matrix`, this can be done using `lapply`

```
 score2[] <- lapply(score2, function(x) ifelse(grepl('^...$', x), 
                   paste(x, x, sep="/"),x))
```